# How do I select attributes from multiple entities? using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

The question is to find names and telephone numbers of all customers who borrowed a particular CD and are supposed to return by a particular date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$sql = "select name AND telephone from customers ";
$data = mysqli_query($sql);
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data) ) {
print_r($row);
}
```

names and telephone numbers are attributes. Customers and CD are entity sets. Customers have the relation "rent" to CD. Rent includes the attributes date and period.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query is invalid.

AND does not appear in the SELECT, use a comma ','.

Use AND in your WHERE clause to filter results.

i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE borrow_id = 1 AND date < '2013-01-01 00:00:00;
```

Comment: I have a question when you use "*" does it select all customers or just all attributes connected to customers? For instance, in this case I have name, telephone and SSN for a customer. I only want to select name and telephone. Can I just write "SELECT name AND telephone FROM customers WHERE ..."?

Comment: Also instead borrow_id, should I just put the name of the CD since it says who borrowed a particular CD?

Comment: As mentioned above, yes you can select the information you want, but why do you insist on using AND? Quote from my original reply...AND does not appear in the SELECT, use a comma ','.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the previous answer, you have to use a comma to delimit your attributes:

> select name, telephone from customers

The "*" selects all columns (you name it "attributes") from your table "customers".

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. Also instead borrow_id, should I just put the name of the CD since it says who borrowed a particular (specific title) CD? Will that still return the correct data?

Comment: No, like that:
 `SELECT name, telephone FROM customers WHERE title LIKE "your specific title" `